# How to use PyTorch to softmax only the upper triangular elements of a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, tensor, softmax

Given input like:

```
tensor([[[1.9392, -1.9266,  0.9664],
         [0.0000, -1.9266,  0.9664],
         [0.0000, -0.0000,  0.9664]]])
```

My desired output is:

```
tensor([[[0.4596,  0.0096, 0.1737],
         [0.0000,  0.0096, 0.1737],
         [0.0000, -0.0000, 0.1737]]])
```

I.e. just calculating the function over the upper triangular elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the upper triangular elements with `torch.triu_indices`:

```py
t = tensor([[1.9392, -1.9266, 0.9664], 
            [0.0000, -1.9266, 0.9664], 
            [0.0000, -0.0000, 0.9664]]) 

idx = torch.triu_indices(*t.shape)
soft = F.softmax(t[idx[0], idx[1]], dim=0)
```

If you want to reassign the values as in your desired output:

```py
>>> t[idx[0], idx[1]] = soft
>>> t
```

```
tensor([[0.4596,  0.0096, 0.1737],
        [0.0000,  0.0096, 0.1737],
        [0.0000, -0.0000, 0.1737]])
```

Comment: if tensor shape is 3D, for example r.shape=torch.tensor([5,3,3])
i think use for loop like this 
`for i in range(r.shape[0]):
sub_r = r[i]
other code like you`
it's right?